# Invalid receiver type when releasing a variable

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, memory-management

I am learning a lot about memory management but this one problem has me wondering.

In a class method I create a variable:

```
TBXMLElement *pieceXML = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"piece" 
                                parentElement:rootElement];
```

And the release it at the end of the method:

```
[pieceXML release];
```

But I get the error: `Invalid receiver type 'TBXMLElement *'`

The implemenation of `childElementNamed:parentElement:` is below

```
+ (TBXMLElement*) childElementNamed:(NSString*)aName parentElement:(TBXMLElement*)aParentXMLElement{
    TBXMLElement * xmlElement = aParentXMLElement->firstChild;
    const char * name = [aName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    while (xmlElement) {
        if (strlen(xmlElement->name) == strlen(name) && memcmp(xmlElement->name,name,strlen(name)) == 0) {
            return xmlElement;
        }
        xmlElement = xmlElement->nextSibling;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I am trying to understand how I can predict this happening again and any references to reading is welcome since I am not sure how to find the reason for this even after looking.

Thanks.

Comment: Is TBXMLElement a descendant of NSObject where the release method is declared.

Comment: According to Bavarious it seems to be a C `struct`.

Comment: As described [here](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/API.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TBXMLElement` is not an Objective-C class — it’s a C `struct` instead.

This means that `pieceXML` is not an Objective-C object, hence you cannot send it any Objective-C messages. In particular, you cannot send it `-release`.

Comment: Thanks, so how would I release it? Or is that not needed at all?

Comment: @Jero As far as I can tell, you don’t need `free(pieceXML)` (akin to releasing Objective-C objects). It looks like `TBXML` owns and releases all objects/memory it creates.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to release objects you get from helper methods like `childElementNamed:parentElement:` Only release if you alloc or copy. There are a few exceptions but this is the rule of thumb.

Comment: This is how I understood it also. Would you have a good tip for the most common case when it isn't true? This would help me rap my head around it better. Thanks!

Comment: Well, also properties with the (retain) or (copy) attribute should be released. Onjects created with [yourClassName new] should be released. No need to release if you used a pool or autorelease. You can find [gory details at this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB).